# How to work out which package is unsetting keybindings?

Tags: emacs

Something in my config is unsetting/overwriting some standard keybindings for `C-c C-e` so that commands in various major modes don't work properly. In AUCTeX `C-c C-e` should start the "insert environment" dialogue and in org-mode the same keys should start the export/publish dialogue, but in both of these modes `C-c C-e` is undefined and emacs just waits for more input.

I know I could start emacs with `-Q` and load packages until something breaks (and if I load emacs that way and open a file in org-mode, the keybindings work as they should) but, like lots of people, at some point my init file became monstrously big. Is there a quicker, smarter way?

[EDIT] Nothing in my config is unsetting `C-c C-e` explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

The debugger might give you enough clues to sort it out. Try adding the following to the beginning of your `.emacs`:

```
(debug-on-entry 'global-unset-key)
```

You might need to try `'local-unset-key` as well. For details see the [debugger manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html#Debugging).

Comment: Good suggestion, but hasn't helped unfortunately. Debugging showed me that the `mwheel` package was the only one calling `global-unset-key`, but removing it hasn't help. Apparently no package is calling `local-unset-key`. Weird.

Comment: Very strange. For trouble shooting, I open one emacs instance, comment out half the `.emacs` with `M-;` (and save the file), then open a second instance (without the `-Q` flag). If the problem persists in the second instance, close it and comment out half of the remaining .emacs code in the first instance. Repeating this process you can narrow down your search pretty quickly, even with a big config file. Sorry, that's all I've got :(

Comment: *Setting* a binding to `nil` is the same as *unsetting* it (and in fact you will observe that this is exactly what the two functions mentioned actually do), so you can't trap all relevant occurrences with that suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Binary search is your friend.

Go to the middle of your `.emacs` and add `(error "here")`, then launch Emacs and see if the problem persists.

If it does, then insert another error line half way between the current and the top of the file, if not, comment out the current error and add one half way between the current and the bottom.

Repeat the bisection process until you isolate the line or two which are responsible for causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `C-h k C-c C-e` to find out which function is bound to your combination.

In the popped up help buffer, you will get the function name, its documentation and a link to the file where it is defined. Follow that link and you will end up at the place of the function definition.

At this point, it should be simple to identify which package that is responsible for redefinition of your keybinding using the name of the file.

If this does not help, you could `M-x rgrep` in your customization directory for 'C-c C-e' or 'C-e' and manually check everything.

Comment: The trouble is this combination is undefined so `C-h k` doesn't help. Nothing in my config is unsetting the combination explicitly but I suppose something I'm loading must be.

Comment: A variation on this, suggested by  Raffaele Ricciardi on gnu.emacs.help solved it for me in the end: `C-c C-e C-h` lists all the bindings (not just in the current major/minor modes) that use this combination. This pointed me in the direction of `eclim` which was the culprit.